# Hide functionality of application based on the type of user logged into the system in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-authorization

I am building a web application where each user can have different roles associated and each role for the system are hierarchically stored in the database. When the user logs into the system highest role is fetched and respective functionalities are shown on the UI while the user traversing through the application can also switch to a different role using switch role option available, when he/she clicks for different role the partial views(with different functionality) and few buttons should be hidden from the view based on hierarchy of the role selected.

As per my understanding, `custom authorization` can be used to check whether the user has access to a particular page and navigate to a page requested(if authorized) or login page(anonymous user), this will have the control over page level, How to achieve the control over the elements viz. buttons, grids etc.(refer scenario below) in a page based on the role of a user?

**Scenario**: Assuming an employee has the two roles as Admin and Developer the profile page should include initiate payroll button only if the role is of type admin.

Is it good practice to mix MVC and FormsAuthentication together?

Comment: Are you using the ASP.NET identity system? The type of user authentication is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Javascript to reload the page whenever a role is changed and insert a code snippet to check if a user is in a role and then display appropriate elements.

for example,

```
@{
   if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
            {
                <a href="http://www.google.com">Click Here to go to google</a>
            }

 }
```

this code checks in authenticated user is admin and displays a link. If user is not admin, the link is not displayed.